# Incorrect Item gets deleted in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

After I delete a list item ex:2nd item out of 4 from the below code by clicking delete button on the row, it shows 1,2,3 in view instead of 1,3,4. When I debug the view it shows right value, however on page rendering TextBoxFor AeroDromeID is showing wrong. Also the delete aerodrome button shows the right value. Can some one help me to fix this.

Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    [MultipleButton(Name = "action", Argument = "DeleteAerodrome")]
    public ActionResult DeleteAerodrome(FormCollection fc)
    {
        int AerodromeID = Int32.Parse(fc["action:DeleteAerodrome"]);
        var studentSignoutModel = new StudentSignoutViewModel();
        UpdateModel<StudentSignoutViewModel>(studentSignoutModel);
        if (studentSignoutModel.Aerodromes.Count > 0)
            studentSignoutModel.Aerodromes.RemoveAll(m => m.AerodromeID == AerodromeID);
        return View("StudentSignoutStageView", studentSignoutModel);
    }
```

View

```
@if (Model.Aerodromes != null && Model.Aerodromes.Any())
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < Model.Aerodromes.Count; i++)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => Model.Aerodromes[i].AerodromeID, new { @class = "form-control"})</td>
                                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => Model.Aerodromes[i].CloudBase, new { @class = "form-control" })</td>

                                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => Model.Aerodromes[i].Visibility, new { @class = "form-control" })</td>

                                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => Model.Aerodromes[i].Wind, new { @class = "form-control" })</td>

                                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => Model.Aerodromes[i].Crosswind, new { @class = "form-control" })</td>

                                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => Model.Aerodromes[i].InterTempo, new { @class = "form-control" })</td>
                                    <td>
                                    <input type="submit" id="BtnDelAerodrome" value="@Model.Aerodromes[i].AerodromeID" name="action:DeleteAerodrome" style="font-size:1em" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the record with AerodromeID = '+ @Model.Aerodromes[i].AerodromeID);" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: What is your specific problem ? Use breakpoints in your code and inspect the value of variables as needed. (ex : AerodromeID  in the action method)

Comment: Actually when it hits view, the collection shows 1,3,4 in aerodromeid. However when it renders it shows 123 in the page, which is weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there should be a bug with Data Binding concept while rendering from server side, when we use TextBoxFor. 
When I use html tag input with the model binder,it worked. 
This is easily replicable.